# How to get unique values from data range in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column whose rows are:

> Facebook, Skype
>   Facebook, Skype
>   Facebook, Twitter, Skype
>   Facebook, Twitter
>   Facebook, Skype
>   Facebook, Skype
>   Facebook, Twitter, Skype
>   Facebook, Skype, Instagram, Viber

How can I pick only unique values from this data range so that the result is:

> Facebook, Skype, Twitter, Instagram, Viber

Comment: Are the columns to the right of this column empty?

Comment: @JasonAller yes. Just to say, this is all in one column..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have data like this in column **A**:

[image]

Running this VBA Macro:

```
Sub GatherUniques()
    Dim N As Long, cl As Collection
    Dim i As Long
    Set cl = New Collection
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next

    For i = 1 To N
        st = Replace(Cells(i, 1).Text, " ", "")
        ary = Split(st, ",")
        For Each a In ary
            cl.Add a, CStr(a)
        Next a
    Next i

    On Error GoTo 0
    st = cl.Item(1)
    For i = 2 To cl.Count
        st = st & "," & cl.Item(i)
    Next i
    Range("B1").Value = st
End Sub
```

Will produce:

[image]

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: that looks super complicated but it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use notepad++ or ms word.  Copy/paste the column into it.  Find/replace ", " by tab.  Copy/paste back in excel. Or if this is the only data in the worksheet you can try to save it as a csv file and open it back in excel.

Comment: If I export it to csv I could do it in python too :) Unfortunately I have to do it in excel

Answer (score 0):

Under Data use the "Text to Columns" button and in the wizard select "delimited" and "comma". This will split the data into separate bits which will allow the next step to grab the unique values.

Then under Data use "Advanced Filter" for each column and select "Copy to another location", for "List range" select a column from the newly expanded range of data, and check "unique records only" and pick a "Copy to" location.

Alternatively you could copy the split columns under each other and perform the advanced filter once.

The collation back into a single cell separated by commas can be done in a variety of ways.